# Unable to install car package

Tags: r

I am unable to install the car package using version 3.4.4 in r. I keep getting error messages:

> warning in install.packages : package 'car' not available (for R version 3.4.4)

I tried using the normal function `install.packages('car')` and also

```
install.packages('car', dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
```

but I'm still having the same error.

Comment: `car` needs newer version of `R`. You must have at least `3.5.0`

Comment: `car` package requires a [`R` version higher than 3.4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/index.html).

Comment: Thank you! I installed the latest version of r and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Try installing an old version of `car` that does not require `R 3.5`:

```
library(devtools)
install_version("car", version = "3.0-2", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```